# copy local file to remote server in ubuntu terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, copy

Jeez, where's Windows drag and drop when you need it. How can I achieve this simple task?

In Ubuntu Terminal I have the prompt:

```
metheuser@metheuser-HP-Pavilion-g6:~$
```

I make it:

```
metheuser@metheuser-HP-Pavilion-g6:~$ cp thefilethefilethefile.txt  theserver@theserver.com
```

hit ENTER and all I get is the prompt again : `metheuser@metheuser-HP-Pavilion-g6:~$`

Then I log into `theserver@theserver.com` and the file isn't in the root directory.

I also tried :

```
scp thefilethefilethefile.txt theserver@theserver.com
```

to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a `:` at the end of the hostname in `scp`.

Comment: ha. That's it. Put this as an answer and I'll mark it correct, thanks.

Comment: FYI: You can mount the remote server using SFTP in the file browser and drag and drop to your heart's content. No additional software required over a standard Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man scp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/scp.1):

```
 scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
     [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
     [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Note that both host specifications include `:`. `scp` uses the `:` to determine whether the argument is a hostname or just another file. So, you need to include a `:` after the hostname:

```
scp thefilethefilethefile.txt theserver@theserver.com:
```

The remote path is optional: if not given, it defaults to the home directory on the remote server.